# How to get sum of int with date in sql query?

Tags: postgresql, date, count, sum

I have the following query and I would like to add all the views of a specific date as shown below.

```
SELECT SUM("videoView"."views"), "videoView"."startDate"::timestamp::date
FROM "videoView" 
WHERE "videoView"."videoId" =23 
AND ("videoView"."startDate"::timestamp::date)= '2021/11/25'
GROUP BY "videoView"."startDate"
```

The result I want is:

```
sum     date
3       2021/11/25
```

The result i am getting is

```
sum      date 
2        2021/11/25
1        2021/11/25
```

Comment: `GROUP BY "videoView"."startDate"::timestamp::date` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @joachim-isaksson, You can do this like following:

```
SELECT SUM("videoView"."views"), "videoView"."startDate"::timestamp::date
FROM "videoView" 
WHERE "videoView"."videoId" =23 
AND ("videoView"."startDate"::timestamp::date)= '2021/11/25'
GROUP BY "videoView"."startDate"::timestamp::date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM(WordCount) as 'words per day' 
from @WordsCount 
group by DateAdded
```